# How do I add recent posts to the menu?

Tags: menus, navigation, sub-menu, recent-posts

How to add recents posts to the menu? Entries with pictures. "Menu-item-object-custom" items in a div container?

What I have now is:
header.php

```
wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
        'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
        'menu_class'     => 'display_lasts_ten_posts_for_categories_menu_item',
        'walker'         => new WPSE_78121_Sublevel_Walker,
        )
    );
```

functions.php

```
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items','display_lasts_ten_posts_for_categories_menu_item',10,3);
function display_lasts_ten_posts_for_categories_menu_item( $items, $menu, $args ) {

$menu_order = count($items);
$child_items = array();

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( 'category' != $item->object || ('category' == $item->object && get_category_children($item->object_id)) )
        continue;
    $category_ten_last_posts = array(
        'numberposts' => 3,
        'cat' => $item->object_id,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'meta_query'     => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'wazny',
                'value'   => 0,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        ),
    );
    foreach ( get_posts( $category_ten_last_posts ) as $post ) {

        $post->menu_item_parent = $item->ID;
        $post->post_type = 'nav_menu_item';
        $post->object = 'custom';
        $post->type = 'custom';
        $post->menu_order = ++$menu_order;
        $post->title = $post->post_title;
        $post->url = get_permalink( $post->ID );
        $child_items[]= $post;

    }

}
return array_merge( $items, $child_items );
}


class WPSE_78121_Sublevel_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='sub-menu'><div class='sub-menu-wrap'>\n";
}
function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</div></ul>\n";
}
}
```

I want to achieve this effect:
[image]